# Negative granting

Tags: negation, modal-verbs

I want to say for example to my kid that tomorrow he has the option to not wear formal shirts in school. What is the best way to say that ?
"You can not to wear formal shirt tomorrow"  ?


Or in some situations I want to say that you have the ability to not to watch this and it is not mandatory :
"You can not to watch this movie" ???

Comment: "You have permission to not wear a formal shirt tomorrow."  And "You are not required to watch this movie."

Comment: "You don't have to wear a formal shirt tomorrow", "You don't have to watch this movie", "You can watch this movie if you want to".

Comment: *"You need not wear a formal shirt tomorrow."*

Comment: But why say it in the negative?  Why not say, "Guess what! You can wear any shirt you like tomorrow!"

Comment: @Jim: Not having to wear a formal shirt is not the same as being able to wear any shirt whatsoever.

Comment: Of course it's not.  But I think it illustrates the point I was trying to make given the information I had.  Obviously the *actual* sentence should be altered to fit the *actual* parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with a modal.  Notice that in the preceding sentence, the negation applies logically to the entire sentence, not (you can do it with a modal), even though the "n't" comes after the "can".  If I wanted to express (you can (not do it with a modal)), meaning that you have the ability to fail to do it with a modal, where would the "not" come?  Right after the "can", which is the exact same place it comes for the first interpretation.  Two quite different meanings would have to be expressed the same way, with "can't".

So, unfortunately, it's just a quirk of English that an interpretation with "not" in the scope of "can" is not available, because it would be misinterpreted to mean the negation of the "can" sentence.  It's the same problem if you use the "may" of permission rather than "can".